# Regex [0-9]* matches empty string on "(2434525)"

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to match all numbers in a string, this is an example code:

```py
re.search(r'[0-9]*', '(123)').group() # outputs: ''

re.search(r'[0-9]*', '123)').group() # outputs: '123'

re.search(r'[0-9]+', '(123)').group() # outputs: '123'
```

Why is this strange behavior happening here?

Comment: There is a sequence of zero digits at the beginning of `(123)`.

Comment: @khelwood In this case shouldn't it return all results, instead of just the first one, as I believe, from the group method we are supposed to get all matched results only, right?

Comment: @khelwood also on regexr.com, I am able to select the numbers, but not in python.

Comment: "shouldn't it return all results"—No, `search` will find the first match. The first match is `''` at position zero. If you only want nonempty matches, use `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: I believe because `*` matches `0 or more` so the first match is `` which is "0" or not a match but it's also fine, + is looking for at least a match so the first number that it finds is the `123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `re.search` will stop on first match.

`re.search(r'[0-9]*', '(123)').group()` - will search for digits starting from empty string to infinity long string, and since first char is `(`, it marches empty string.

`re.search(r'[0-9]*', '123)').group()` - since first char is digit, it will try to get longest match.

`re.search(r'[0-9]+', '(123)').group()` - will search for digits starting from at least one char string to infinity long string, and since first char is `(`, it will skip `(` and will start from first digit and will try to get longest match.

`*` is `{0,}` and `+` is `{1,}`

this is great resource to play with regex https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks, for both the explanation and the great resource link